# Scala Slick / ScalaQuery BigDecimal creates decimal(10,0) how to allow decimals?

Tags: database, scala, playframework-2.0, scalaquery, slick

How do I tell Slick to create a Decimal SQL type which allows for decimals?
It seems that by default Slick doesn't allows for decimals which I noticed with the below code. It creates a column with the data type `decimal(10,0)` in MySQL.

I have the following model in my Scala code:

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

case class TimeType(id: Option[Int], name: String,
  employeeMultiplier: BigDecimal, employerMultiplier: BigDecimal)

object TimeTypes extends Table[TimeType]("timeType") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def employeeMultiplier = column[BigDecimal]("employeeMultiplier")
  def employerMultiplier = column[BigDecimal]("employerMultiplier")
  def * = id.? ~ name ~ employeeMultiplier ~ employerMultiplier <> (TimeType, TimeType.unapply _)
}
```

During startup I create this table using Slick unless it already exists with this code

```
...
lazy val database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())

database.withSession {
  if (MTable.getTables("timeType").list.isEmpty) {
    TimeTypes.ddl.create
    ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not ideal, but you could try this:

```
def employeeMultiplier = 
  column[BigDecimal]("employeeMultiplier", O.DBType("decimal(10, 4)"))
```

MySQL accepts just `DECIMAL`, in which case it creates the field with it's defaults that
happen to be `DECIMAL(10, 0)`. I'm not sure if there's any other way to tell Slick/ScalaQuery that you want certain options for your fields.

Comment: Seems that with Slick 3+ one should be using `O.SqlType` instead of `O.DBType`.